# Python Queue consumer

Tags: python, thread-safety

I am new to python, and started to learn the few advanced concepts. Here I am using python queue for consuming and producing thread. Is this a thread safe? Here I am adding list items to the queue and retrieving it in the consumer thread. Is there any best way of doing it?

```
from queue import Queue
import threading
import time

class producer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, list_of_numbers):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.list_items = list_of_numbers

    def run(self):
        for i in self.list_items:
            queue.put(str(i))

class consumer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while queue.not_empty:
            queue_ret = queue.get()
            print("Retrieved", queue_ret)


queue = Queue()
producers = producer([10,20,5,4,3,2,1])
consumers = consumer()

producers.start()
consumers.start()
producers.join()
consumers.join()
```

Comment: My question is how to end the consumer thread?.

Answer (score 3):

First initialize your consumer class with the queue.

Then add queue.task_done() at the end of your consumer thread class. That will tell threads to ignore that queue item in future queue.get() calls.  Eventually that means your queue will "empty" and the threads will complete their work.

```
class consumer(threading.Thread):

  def __init__(self, queue):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.queue = queue

  def run(self):
      while queue.not_empty:
          queue_ret = self.queue.get()
          print("Retrieved", queue_ret)
          self.queue.task_done()

# to start your threads, for example 5 threads
for i in range(5):
    consumers = consumer(queue)
    consumers.start()
```

Comment: don't you need to join the queue at some point?

Answer (score 1):

Docs explicitly state that Queue is thread-safe:

> The Queue module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues. It
>   is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be
>   exchanged safely between multiple threads.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

Comment: @SrikanthBhandary this is completely different question

Answer (score 0):

To finish consumer threads, you can push sentinel values into the queue as follow:

```
from queue import Queue
import threading
import time

class producer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, list_of_numbers):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.list_items = list_of_numbers

    def run(self):
        for i in self.list_items:
            queue.put(str(i))
        print("Producer Finished")

class consumer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        done = False
        while not done:
            queue_ret = queue.get()
            if queue_ret is None:
                done = True
            else:
                print("Retrieved", queue_ret)
            queue.task_done()
        print("Consumer Finished")


queue = Queue()
producers = [producer([10,20,5,4,3,2,1])]
consumers = [consumer()]

for producer in producers:
    producer.start()

for consumer in consumers:
    consumer.start()

for producer in producers:
    producer.join()

for consumer in consumers:
    queue.put(None)

for consumer in consumers:
    consumer.join()

print("Finished")
```